# Retrieve Unique Values and Counts For Each

Tags: mysql, count, unique, duplicates

Is there a simple way to retrieve a list of all unique values in a column, along with how many times that value appeared?

Example dataset:

```
A
A
A
B
B
C
```

... Would return:

```
A  |  3
B  |  2
C  |  1
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use GROUP BY:

```
select value, count(*) from table group by value
```

Use HAVING to further reduce the results, e.g. only values that occur more than 3 times:

```
select value, count(*) from table group by value having count(*) > 3
```

Comment: select value, count(*) from table group by value having count(*) > 3

Is count(*) only calculated once here?

Comment: Ahh! Thank you so much for this.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT id,COUNT(*) FROM file GROUP BY id
```